# Show 0 in empty cell of pivot table. Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle11g

I have a pivot table showing the total of orders in each month of year. Each column is a year and each row is a month. Some months don't have values at all, e.g Sept 2006. There is still a 2006 column for other months that have values and there is still a Sept row for the other years. Just the cell for Sept 2006 is empty.

How can I have a 0 put in this cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot table in what? Excel? can't you just do that in Excel? well if not...

Just because the columns have a 2006 and the rows have a Sept, doesn't mean your data source has a row for Sept 2006. If it does then Lynette has your answer. If it doesn't you'll need to outer join to a table/sql of all months and years to create your null records. And then you can coalesce those nulls to zero.

Comment: I'm using the Pivot function in SQL for Oracle. There is no data for Sept 2006. I guess I'll have to do what you said and join to a table of months.

Comment: So can you accept the answer as correct if that fixes your issue? Of course the table can be real or virtual. I suggest just building a date table... tremendously useful in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

Use nvl(value, 0) in your query. It substitutes NULL (empty) with 0.

Comment: You're assuming that row is already there. Nothing that's been said leads to that conclusion.

Comment: The remark "just the cell for Sept 2006 is empty" lets me think that there actually *is* a cell. If that's true, there must be a row where that cell is in :-)

Answer (score 0):

If by "empty" you mean NULL, try using Coalesce( UrMonth, 0 )

Comment: Maybe. If there's a row for Sept 2006.